# C: Linking error for function of same signature

Tags: c, linker, linker-errors

I am getting a linking error when i run my program, even though the function signature is the same for both functions in test.h and test.c :

test.h :

```
void function(int);
```

test.c :

```
#include "test.h"
#include "stdio.h"

static void function(int n) {
    printf("%d\n", n);
}
```

main.c :

```
#include "test.h"

int main() {

    function(5);
    return 0;
}
```

this is the output:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_function", referenced from:
      _main in ccNaA2H2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

In class, I learned that the function signature is the function name and its parameters.
So, why doesn't my program in main call function(5) in test.h which will call the function(5) in test.c ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static` at global scope (outside of functions) means that it is only visible in this file (It has internal linkage). So, the `static void function(int n)` in test.c is not visible from main.c.

For the call `function(5);` in main, the compiler sees the function prototype in test.h, but the linker cannot find an implementation of it, because the function in the c file is `static`.

Solution: remove the word `static`, if you want to use the function in a different file.

Answer (score 0):

In `test.c` you declared your function as `static` which means, it will not be visible outside that module. Remove the `static` keyword.